# How to change delete button font in UITableView cell?

Tags: ios

I want to add a custom font to the delete button in UITableViewCell when the red delete button is being displayed.

Any ideas how to achieve it on iOS 5?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

But not the font. You'll have to create a whole custom button.